# Re-setting up working project on local machine

Tags: php, .htaccess, symfony-1.4, virtualhost

I'm working on a symfony 1.4 project which is working, i wanted to work on a local copy on my personal machine; so I've settled a virtual host (I'm on a Windows 8.1 with xamppp web server). 
I'm getting a 500 error when trying to access from browser by giving "joyaa" (it's the virtualhost alias), and in some of my test I had a redirect to the project working on the server (it's a statement in .htaccess)

This is the virtual host defining:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName joyaa
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/yaol/web"
DirectoryIndex index.php
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/yaol/web">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
</Directory>

Alias /sf C:/xampp/htdocs/yaol/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/yaol/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
</Directory>

Alias /joyaa "C:/xampp/htdocs/yaol/web"

<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/yaol/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

and this is the .htaccess defining:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /joyaa
  RewriteRule ^yaol(.*)$ http://www.arcadja.com/joyaa$1 [L,R=301]
  # we check if the .html version is here (caching)
  RewriteRule ^$ index.html [QSA]
  RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [QSA]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

  # no, so we redirect to our front web controller
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]

</IfModule>
```

Probably it's a configuration problem but I'm not sure about where to look at... Please help. Thanks

Comment: Error 500 is a server configuration error. Your .htaccess looks okay - Check the apache log for more detail on could be causing it.

Comment: ServerName expects a proper TLD. ServerAlias will allow for aliasing.

Comment: @SukhdevMohan: Can you check your Apache error.log to see what's causing 500 error?

Comment: This is the latest error.log http://pastebin.com/ZcX80kan.. Can't ffigure what is wrong...

Comment: @SukhdevMohan It appears you have different log for the site.  Check the site log file for error details.

Comment: Yes symfony has a log section but isn't writing anything there... Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: @kami any of you guys have any clue to solve this? please help guys..